# Getting connection refused error when using Path variable in spring MVC with Angularjs http.get method

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I am getting a connection refused error when trying to use Spring MVC path variable with Angularjs http.get
Kindly help
I am making this call in the angularjs controller

```
$http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN').
```

and mapping it to spring mvc controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stocklist/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Stock> stocklist(@PathVariable("id") String id, Locale locale, Model model)
```

Can you please let me know why its not able to recognize the url pattern above.

Comment: connection refused means that the browser won't even connect to the server. So it's not a mapping problem. Post the exzct and complete error message.

Comment: You have to put more informations. The exact error message. And also the complete source code of the controller please